# integrating google assistant with other android apps

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, api-ai

Is it possible to open an android application and perform a certain task as a response to google assistant chat. how to code the google assistant app in node.js for that?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. And in most cases, you don't want to do this anyway. The Assistant runs on multiple platforms, not just Android, and is meant for more of a conversational user interface.

A slightly longer answer is that, while it is possible, it would be a bad idea. The Assistant is good for hands-free, and sometimes eyes-free, operation, and directing the user to an application treats it just as a launcher. The better solution would be to move some of the logic you have in your app into a webhook and provide a conversational way to get the same information.

If you insist on going to an app, however, there are two ways you can do this:

- You can have your webhook (node.js in your case) trigger a notification using something like [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) which would either create a notification on your device or trigger an intent in your app.
- You can return a [basic card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) containing a link URL that will trigger an Intent in your app.